# Stop mouseout events when mouse move in specified element

Tags: jquery

All , I knew `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, these events are trigger when the mouse moves in and out of elements AND it's descendants. 
Let me take a example ,Say you have a dom structure like below:

```
<div id="top">
   <div class="container">
      <!--<div class="head">
      </div>-->
      <div class="content">
         <!--maybe there are many nested `div.contiainer` as children directly or not directly.-->
      <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Supposed the mouse move in the `div.container` we append a `div.head` in there. and when mouse out we remove the `div.head` which was created when mouse in.

so the code will looks like below .

```
    $("div.container").on("mouseover",function(){//append div.head})
.on("mouseout",function(){//remove the div.head});
```

So my question is I want to whether there is possiblility to stop the event `mouseout` when mouse move in `div.head` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.mouseout` will fire when you leave the element its bound to - even if it is a child element. You are better off using `.mouseleave` which will only fire when you leave the element (not hover over a child) http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zN4FF/

Comment: Hi ,Friend ,I believe the code will be very verbose if the dom  contains nested `div.container`. thanks.